# Delete words from the built-in dictionary?

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, auto-correct, dictionary

Using Android 6. Auto correct usually works very well, so I don't want to turn it off. However on some occasions it stubbornly 'corrects' some words which I don't want, which is *extremely* inconvenient.

These words are not in my personal dictionary. I've tried the following:

- add the word I want to my personal dictionary
- add the word I want to the 'all languages' dictionary
- add the wrong word (to which it tends to autocorrect) to the custom dictionary and then remove that
- repeatedly type in the word and when it autocorrects, click it and set it back to what it was, hoping that Android will learn my preference (I really tried this many many interations)

It's driving me nuts. How do I force Android NOT to autocorrect certain words? Or rather, how do delete some words from its own dictionary?

P.S. I know several similar questions like these were posted before, but they were all either outdated (apparently referring to much older Android versions) or the posted answers didn't work (I've tried them all). Quite some references to Android in 2011 are no longer relevant.

P.P.S. I'm using a Nexus 5, default built-in keyboard.

Comment: Keyboards tend to be brand-specific. Can you tell the brand and model of your device?

Comment: Right, I added the Nexus 5 spec (that's from LG) so I'm using just plain stock Android 6.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of a word you're trying to type, and the word it autocorrects to?

Comment: @DanHenderson in Dutch for example, when I type `daf`, it autocorrects to `DAF`, which I never want (it could autocorrect to `dag` or `dat` which are legit words, but I *never* want `DAF`).

Comment: Similar problem here. I have Vanilla Android UI on my Moto G3, I'm using default keyboard (which is Google keyboard). When I type `hi`, it auto corrects to `Hi`. Super annoying.

Comment: Four years later, this is still a problem without, apparently, a solution.  In my case, as the I and U are right next to each other, my phone often illiterately types "u" when I type "I".  I wish I could remove "u" from the built-in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work to misspell it and then not press spacebar. When the suggestion pops up (on my Gboard, there are always corrections at the top of the keyboard) you can see the word you do not want it to change to if you were to press spacebar. You then long-press that suggestion and then it gives you an option to remove that suggestion. I just did it, and it seems to work so far. I have tried to misspell the word I am having a problem with in all possible ways, and so far it has worked.